# Getting MalformedPolicyDocumentException error when attaching KMS key policy to key using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

With Terraform, I am trying to attach a iam policy document to aws_kms_key_policy resource. I get this error when trying to apply:

> ╷
> │ Error: attaching KMS Key policy (d748265c-7fcc-4e3c-8f85-5fe6eefb6e8a): updating
> policy: MalformedPolicyDocumentException: The new key policy will not allow you to
> update the key policy in the future.
> │
> │   with module.*****.aws_kms_key_policy.origin_access,
> │   on ../modules/ui/kms.tf line 12, in resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "origin_access":
> │   12: resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "origin_access" {

This is the policy document:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "key_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "Allow cloudfront KMS Use"

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudfront.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.account}:root"]
    }
    
    actions = [
      "kms:*"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceArn"
      values   = ["${aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution.arn}"]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the KMS resources:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "origin_bucket_key" {
  description             = "This key is used to encrypt bucket objects"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "key_alias" {
  name          = "alias/${var.env}-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.origin_bucket_key.key_id
}

resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "origin_access" {
  key_id = aws_kms_key.origin_bucket_key.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.key_policy.json
 }
```

FYI, I did get the same error using EOF and attaching policy directly to aws_kms_key_policy policy field. I tried many other variations but couldn't get it to work. I also have AdministratorAccess attached to my IAM user. Example key policy I am trying to create is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#oac-permission-to-access-s3). Is this error informative and how can I get passed this?

Comment: If you are refering to the document I linked above, it mentions to add the arn. If you are refering to different documentation, please add to comments and ill have a look.

Answer (score 0):

From the help of AWS support and helpful comment by Mark B, I was able to solve the problem. Firstly, I had to delete the key because the error states the key can no longer be updated. Secondly, I had to split the policy into two statements because the original one is considered malformed (information on why at bottom). The proper policy document is below:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "key_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "Allow root KMS Use"

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.account}:root"]
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:*"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid = "Allow cloudfront KMS Use"

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudfront.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "kms:Encrypt",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceArn"
      values   = ["${aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution.arn}"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
The statement was trying to apply a condition to both root IAM user and Cloudfront. The condition was not valid for root user and therefore could never update it.

Comment: Your previous policy applied the `condition` to both CloudFront **and** the root IAM user. That condition would never be valid for the root IAM user, which means that you would no longer be able to manage the KMS key at all. That's why you needed to split out the statements to get this to work, by making the `condition` only apply to CloudFront.